# Creating a mask for all browsers using css-transforms encountering issues with positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-transforms

I need to create a mask to overlay an image in all browsers based on `vh` (no `clip-path`)

I'm using a div with a rotational transform as a mask, then on the inner reversing the rotation.

The issue I'm having is content inside of the inner isn't positioning correctly. The image needs to be aligned to top left of the inner container.

I have tried:

- positioning with top and left values to no effect.
- Using transform to move the inner container works but i cant find how the values required are calculated.

https://jsfiddle.net/owfgLnv7/5/

```
.container {
  width: 70vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.tri {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70vh;
  height: 70vh;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: calc((100vh - 70vh) / 2);
  transform-origin: center center;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.reset-tri {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
}

.inner-container {
  background: black;
}
```

Need to get the image so that it is top left aligned and flowing normally

Comment: If you go to the link you see the image is not aligned inside the diamond to the top left

Comment: The img inside of the diamond should be aligned to the top left not some arbitrary point in space

Comment: Can you not see the link?

Comment: The link is as it is NOW...not what it **should** look like.

Comment: So the <img> Element should be aligned to the top left of the inner-container div.

Comment: You keep repeating the same thing. SHOW us what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: https://ibb.co/VvB7DMh

Pink - IMG
Black - inner
Blue - tri
container- Dark purple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, when elements are *transformed* (rotated here), they are taken out of the flow - so dimensions won't behave as it does when you don't.

One approach is just using simple mathematics:

- if you rotate a square 45deg (you have a 70vh square here) of side `a`, then the *diagonal* will be `√2 * a` ~ `1.414 * a`,
- because `transform-origin` is `center` here, this means you have the *overflowing width or height* equal to `(1.414 * a - a) / 2` or `(1.414 - 1) * a / 2`.
- similar argument can be stated for the width of the `container` which will have a width equal to `width: calc(1.414 * 70vh)`

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
}

.container {
  width: calc(1.414 * 70vh); /* changed */
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.tri {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70vh;
  height: 70vh;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: calc(0.414 * 70vh / 2); /* changed */
  left: calc(0.414 * 70vh / 2); /* added */
  transform-origin: center center;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.reset-tri {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
}

.inner-container {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tri">
      <div class="reset-tri">
        <div class="inner-container">
          <img src="https://openclipart.org/download/230732/360sj3.svg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Using Background Image**

For a near-perfect *masking* you can:

- move the `image` to a `background-image` in the `reset-tri` container and
- add a `scale(1.414)` transform to exactly *fill* the original *un-transformed* `tri` container.

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
}

.container {
  width: calc(1.414 * 70vh); /* changed */
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.tri {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70vh;
  height: 70vh;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: calc(0.414 * 70vh / 2); /* changed */
  left: calc(0.414 * 70vh / 2); /* added */
  transform-origin: center center;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.reset-tri {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.414); /* scale by √2 */
  transform-origin: center center;
  width: 70vh;
  height: 70vh;
  /* use a bacground image */
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://openclipart.org/download/230732/360sj3.svg");
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tri">
      <div class="reset-tri"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Using Image Element**

For a near-perfect *masking* without using `background-image` you can go back to the previous markup and add `object-fit: cover` to the `img` element that fills the dimensions of its wrapper, the `inner-container` - see demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
}

.container {
  width: calc(1.414 * 70vh); /* changed */
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.tri {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70vh;
  height: 70vh;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: calc(0.414 * 70vh / 2); /* changed */
  left: calc(0.414 * 70vh / 2); /* added */
  transform-origin: center center;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.reset-tri {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.414); /* scale by √2 */
  transform-origin: center center;
  width: 70vh;
  height: 70vh;
}

.inner-container {
  height: 100%; /* fill the parent wrapper */
}

.inner-container > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /* the image fills the parent container */
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tri">
      <div class="reset-tri">
        <div class="inner-container">
          <img src="https://openclipart.org/download/230732/360sj3.svg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. However the positioning of the img element is still the issue here. It does not align with the top left of its parent

Comment: Thanks for the background image solution. I still can't see how to position elements inside this however

Comment: @jwtea sorry for the late reply, I thought I'd already updated the answer yesterday... have added both *background-image* and *image element* options above...

Comment: Thank you so much kukkuz. I've managed to avoid using object-fit for this to work in IE with the following thanks for your help!

https://jsfiddle.net/m3p2vacy/1/